# Reposition content on iOS

Tags: css, ipad, swipe

Is it possible to reposition content on my page when it is viewed on an iPad/iPhone for example. I currently have content (jquery flip) with boxes in a grid shape, can these be repositioned with CSS into a horizontal line/carousel-type-thing that can be swiped through on iPad etc.? This would reduce the amount of vertical scrolling on the page.

I'm not sure if media screen is the best option as the resolution of iPads is getting larger and therefore new iPads would display differently to older ones and I'd quite like to keep the grid view for non-mobile device viewing. The problem with selecting based on OS(?) is excluding android/other devices and OSs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to detect mobile OS :

```
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/blackberry/gi)) 
    || (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/gi))) {
        //Cool Stuff Here
    }
```

And this for webkit, maybe you can use it in a little js to trigger CSS:

```
    if ( $.browser.webkit || $.browser.safari){

        //Cool Stuff Here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear why you want to target a particular device rather than a particular device *size*. The latter is easy to do with @media rules. Each iPad version responds to the same @media dimensions, no matter what screen resolution, as is also the case for iPhones (except that iPhone5 is slightly taller – 560px instead of 480px).

Comment: Maybe not a particular device, but to customise/optimise for mobile usage. Do retina iPads respond to min-device-width of 768px and max-device-width of 1024px even though they are 2048px wide?

Comment: "Do retina iPads respond to min-device-width of 768px and max-device-width of 1024px even though they are 2048px wide?". Yes.